# Why my element selector doesn't work after using <script setup> in vue.js?

Tags: javascript, html, vuejs3

Let say I want to change color of my  element. Unfortunately, after use query Selector method, my code doesn't work but blank. Please anyone can solve this?

I try to select my element to change its color using javascript instead of using css

```
<template>
  <br><br><br>
<h1>Dashboard Page Here</h1>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: "xxxView",
}
</script>

<script setup>
const color = document.querySelector('h1');
color.style.color = 'green';
</script>

<style scoped>

</style>
```

Comment: elements in your component won't be available until `onMounted`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`setup`](https://vuejs.org/api/sfc-script-setup.html#basic-syntax) method is executed before the component elements are mounted to the `DOM`, you need to execute the `DOM` operations in the [`onMounted`](https://vuejs.org/api/composition-api-lifecycle.html#onmounted) lifecycle

For example

```
<template>
  <br><br><br>
<h1>Dashboard Page Here</h1>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: "xxxView",
}
</script>

<script setup>
import { onMounted } from 'vue'
onMounted(() => {
  const color = document.querySelector('h1');
  color.style.color = 'green';
})
</script>

<style scoped>

</style>
```

But I suggest you if possible to use [`style`](https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/class-and-style.html#binding-inline-styles) directive instead.

Comment: Thankyou it works, it is more complicated than css after all

Answer (score 0):

One method to access your "DOM" elements in Vue components is using "ref" as the code below:

```html
<template>
  <br><br><br>
  <h1 ref="myHeader">Dashboard Page Here</h1>
</template>


<script setup>
import {ref, onMounted} from "vue";
const myHeader = ref(null)

onMounted(() => {
  myHeader.value.style.color = 'green';
})
</script>

<style scoped>

</style>
```

You can learn more about that in [Vue.js docs](https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/template-refs.html#template-refs)

Comment: thanks by the way, but if you don't mind, can u explain what ref(null) means? Your answer still work even without ref = "myHeader"

Comment: @Farhan Ersavan As I said, according to docs : **"To obtain the reference with Composition API, we need to declare a ref with the same name"**. That **ref(null)** you said is used to define that reference. That is the formal and confident way to access the element or child component that vue suggests.